# Orbeon: submission on change content of input

Tags: orbeon, xforms, submission

I'm creating web service field in my xform file. My destiny is to have two fields, for example: name and welcome message. The scenario is: user write his name in name input field, and when he do this, in welcome message input field appear text from web service. I reach very similar effect, but using button (trigger): user write his name, click on button, and then appear message. I want to do this without button, using some on-change event, but I don't know how.

My code:

```
<fr:grid>                                                                                                
   <xh:tr>                            
      <xh:td> 
         <xf:input bind="name-bind" id="name">
            <xf:label>Your name</xf:label>
         </xf:input> 
      </xh:td>                            
      <xh:td>        
         <xf:input bind="welcome-bind" id="welcome">
            <xf:label>Welcome text</xf:label>
         </xf:input>
         <xf:trigger>                                                                                                            
            <xf:label>Generate welcome from WS</xf:label>                             
            <xf:send ev:event="DOMActivate" submission="my-submission"/>                                                                                                         
         </xf:trigger>                              
      </xh:td>                            
   </xh:tr>                     
</fr:grid>
```

If somebody know how change my code, to reach described effect, give me some advice please.

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like the submission to run when users change the value in the `name` field and leave the field to go to another field (e.g. tabbing out of the field), then you can write:

```
<xf:input bind="name-bind" id="name">
    <xf:label>Your name</xf:label>
    <xf:send ev:event="xforms-value-changed" submission="my-submission"/> 
</xf:input>
```

You can also add `DOMActivate` in addition to `xforms-value-changed` (the value of `ev:event` can be a space separated list of events), if you want the submission to also run if users press *enter* after typing a value in the field.